# how to make sure which star button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter and i have form where i can rate a product . Their I have implemented star buttons. Whenever i click one button, In a label it shows a "Terrible" text and so on. What i need to know is whenever i submit the form i need to make sure user has clicked any star button and given his/her rate. that means giving the rate is required . How can i achieve that . Id id this . but it's always shows "You haven't provided Rating" error message.

businessRateView.php

```
<?php $Vehicleid=$details['id']; ?>
                        <form action="<?php echo 'http://localhost/ci/businessRateCtrl/insertIntoBusinessReview/'.$Vehicleid?> " method="POST">

                        <h2>Rate Ad</h2>
                        <p>All field marked with * are required</p>
                        <div style="color:red">
                    <?php
                        $CI =& get_instance();
                        $CI->load->library('form_validation');
                        echo validation_errors();
                    ?>
                    </div>

                         <div class="spacer-20"></div>
                        <h4>Your rating*</h4>


                        <h1><div class="rating" style="width:200px;float:left;padding-left:1px">
                            <span class="rate-star" data-rate="Excellent">&bigstar;</span> 
                            <span class="rate-star" data-rate="Good" >&bigstar;</span> 
                            <span class="rate-star" data-rate="Okay" >&bigstar;</span>
                            <span class="rate-star" data-rate="Unsatisfied" >&bigstar;</span>
                            <span class="rate-star" data-rate="Terrible" >&bigstar;</span>
                            </div>
                        </h1>

                        <div style="float:right;padding-right:450px">
                        <h3><label id="rateText" name="lblrating"></label></h3>
                        </div>


                        <div class="spacer-20"></div>



                         <h4>Write your review</h4>
                          <div class="spacer-20"></div>
                        <label class="col-md-4"> Title </label> 
                        <input type="text" name="reviewTitle" placeholder="Title your review" class="form-control">     

                        <div class="spacer-20"></div>

                        <label class="col-md-4">Your review </label>       
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="103" name="review" placeholder="Write your review" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        <div class="spacer-20"></div>
                       <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href=<?php echo 'http://localhost/ci/adpreview_ctrl/getad_preview/'.$Vehicleid?>  onclick="return cancelConfirm();">Cancel</a>

                        <input type="submit" name="submitreview" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="SUBMIT">

                        </form>

businessRateCtrl.php

     public function loadReviewPage($vehicleid){


        $data=array();
        $data['details']['id']=$vehicleid;

        $this->load->view('pages/templates/header');
            $this->load->view('pages/businessRateView',$data);
            $this->load->view('pages/templates/footer');



    }

    public function insertIntoBusinessReview($Vehicleid){

          $data=array();
        $data['details']['id']=$Vehicleid;

         $this->form_validation->set_rules
            (
                'lblrating',
                'lblrating', 
                'required',
                array
                (
                    'required'      => 'You have not provided Rating',

                )
            );


              if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
              $this->load->view('pages/templates/header');
                $this->load->view('pages/businessRateView',$data);
                $this->load->view('pages/templates/footer');

            }

            else{
              $this->main_model->insertIntoBusinessReview($Vehicleid);
          //$_SESSION['ads']=$_SESSION['ads']+1;
          $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Thank you! We will post your review soon');
          redirect("<?php echo 'http://localhost/ci/adpreview_ctrl/getad_preview/'.'$Vehicleid' ?>");

        }

mainmodel.php

    public function insertIntoBusinessReview($Vehicleid){

                $rating = $_POST['lblrating'];

                if(($_POST['reviewTitle'])!==null || ($_POST['review'])!==null)
                {
                $title=$_POST['reviewTitle'];
                $review=$_POST['review'];

                $data=array('Vehicleid'=>$Vehicleid,'rating'=>$rating,'title'=>$title,'review'=> $review,'reviewPoster'=>$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['email']);
                $this->db->insert('businessreviews',$data);
                }

                $data=array('Vehicleid'=>$Vehicleid,'rating'=>$rating,'reviewPoster'=>$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['email']);
                $this->db->insert('businessreviews',$data);


            }



Please help me.
```

Comment: One of the ways to implement it is to create a hidden input and name it `lblrating`. Then modify your js, add code that will update value of the `lblrating` input  when a star is clicked. When a user will press the submit button the value of the input will be sent to the server.